# Unable to run program on different backends

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, measurement

```
from qiskit import *

def random_bitstring_generator(bit_number, backend):
    """
    Generate a bitstring with one qubit
    :param bit_number: number of bits that we want to generate
    :param backend: Qiskit hardware or simulator
    :return: string object with random bits
    """

    bitstring = ""

    one_qubit_random_bit_generator_circuit = QuantumCircuit(1,1)
    one_qubit_random_bit_generator_circuit.h(0)
    one_qubit_random_bit_generator_circuit.measure(0,0)

    for _ in range(bit_number):
        counts = execute(one_qubit_random_bit_generator_circuit, backend, shots=1).result().get_counts()
        bit = list(counts.keys())[0]  # we have only one key because shots=1
        bitstring += bit

    return bitstring

provider = IBMQ.load_account()
backend = BasicAer.get_backend('ibmq_santiago')

print(random_bitstring_generator(512, backend)
```

Running the above code in jupyter notebook in quantum lab  gives me error as shown is photo. I am also unable to run the program for a backend other than simuator like melboune, vigo, ourense.[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try to replace

```
backend = BasicAer.get_backend('ibmq_santiago')
```

with

```
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_santiago')
```

Alternativetly, you can also use this code:

```
backend = provider.backends(name = 'ibmq_santiago')[0]
```

You have to use backends available under you account. There are only simulators in BasicAer while the real quantum machines are under the account.

Comment: i login into IBM Q Experience through my google account and i am able to run designed circuits in  a circuit composer on machines like vigo, ourence,melbourne etc.However when trying to run a circuit for which code is written in quantum lab it gives the above error. How  can this be the case that a particular backened is available for me to execute a circuit in GUI and not in quantum lab

Comment: @parth When you use circuit composer, it uses the default open provider. In your code, this line ‘provider = IBMQ.load_account()’ loads your account and gets the default open provider. So the behavior should be consistent between circuit composer and quantum lab.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean, the error specifically says that:

**QiskitBackendNotFoundError: "The 'ibmq_santiago' backend is not installed in your system."**

This means you don't have access to this machine from your account. This machine is either dedicated to only privilege users.

Comment: Santiago is avaiable under free account, it is not dedicated processor

Comment: Thanks Martin. I didn't check. I just wrote the answer based off from what I saw on the error_message. I see your answer to the question now. Nice.

Comment: No problem, recently I had similar issue with connecting to actual quantum processor. Also thanks for vote up.

Comment: i login into IBM Q Experience through my google account and i am able to run designed circuits in a circuit composer on machines like vigo, ourence,melbourne etc.However when trying to run a circuit for which code is written in quantum lab it gives the above error. How can this be the case that a particular backened is available for me to execute a circuit in GUI and not in quantum lab